# exec: "cksum": executable file not found in $PATH in golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to get the cksum of one file using Go by executing the command `cksum`.

Getting the below error:

```
exec: "cksum": executable file not found in $PATH
```

Below is the code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/cksum",dst)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure `cksum` is actually installed under `/bin`?

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for [`exec.Command`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command):

> If name contains no path separators, Command uses LookPath to resolve the path to a complete name if possible. Otherwise it uses name directly.

So it's slightly better to use `cmd := exec.Command("cksum", …)` and let it be found where ever it exists on the path.
Alternatively you should have run `which cksum` which on nearly every unix system will give: `/usr/bin/cksum`.

But better yet, make your code portable to *any* OS that can run Go and use [`hash/crc32`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/crc32/).
Or even better, if you can remove any requirements on having to use CRC32 (which is what the ancient `cksum` uses),
pick one of the other **far superior** hashes from
[`hash/…`](https://golang.org/pkg/hash/#pkg-subdirectories),
[`crypto/…`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/#pkg-subdirectories) (e.g. sha256),
or [`golang.org/x/crypto/…`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto) (e.g. sha3).

Answer (score 1):

> Most of the executable binaries are present under /usr/bin
>   directory,so you need to modify your code as below.

```
cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/cksum",dst)
```